# Display number of wrong attempts of user

Tags: django, django-models

In my django app I want to show that the user has tried logging in with wrong password three times.

I am using **django-brutebuster**

I can see a table in my postgres on migrate named **BruteBuster_failedattempt** which has the following columns :

- id
- username
- IP
- failures
- timestamp

## settings.py

```
Installed Apps:
    ...
    BruteBuster

Middleware
    ...
    BruteBuster.middleware.RequestMiddleware',

Block threshhold
   BB_MAX_FAILURES = 3 
   BB_BLOCK_INTERVAL = 3
```

I want to display the count of failed attempts on my django template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a model, so you can

```
from BruteBuster.models import FailedAttempt
from django.db.models import Sum

total_failed = FailedAttempt.objects.filter(
    username=request.user.username
).aggregate(
    total_failures=Sum('failures')
)['total_failures']
```

There can however be some problems here:

1. `BruteBuster` here tracks the number of failures per username and per IP, so  we need to sum these up;
2. if the user changes their username, then there are no records anymore for this `FailedAttempt`, so it might not work perfectly for such scenarios; and
3. if there are nu failed attempts, then it will return `None`, not `0`, but you can add `or 0` at the end to convert `None` to `0`.